# Why does building a NSFont in initWithFrame: or startAnimation: instead of drawRect: or animateOneFrame: crash my screen saver?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

As a newbie in Objective-C (I'm coming from a Java background), I am trying to build a simple screen saver that displays text.

As far as it goes (that is, using examples from the internet as my education source), it works, but when trying to go back and do things (in my mind) the right way, I'm having some trouble. It's quite possible that my issues stem from a basic misunderstanding of the Objective-C paradigm, but I'm a bit puzzled, so I thank you all in advance.

Working code:

```
NSPoint point;
NSString *string;
NSFont *font;
NSColor *fontColor;
NSDictionary *dictionary;

…

- (void)startAnimation
{
    string = @"Hello, World!";
    point = NSMakePoint(500, 500);

    [super startAnimation];
}

…

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    font = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Verdana"
                           size:18];
    fontColor = [NSColor whiteColor];
    dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font, NSFontAttributeName,
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1], NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName,
                                fontColor, NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                nil];

    [string drawAtPoint:point withAttributes:dictionary];
}

…
```

Broken code:

```
…

- (void)startAnimation
{
    string = @"Hello, World!";
    point = NSMakePoint(500, 500);
    font = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Verdana"
                           size:18];

    [super startAnimation];
}

…

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    fontColor = [NSColor whiteColor];
    dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font, NSFontAttributeName,
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1], NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName,
                                fontColor, NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                nil];

    [string drawAtPoint:point withAttributes:dictionary];
}

…
```

Thank you very kindly in advance for your help!

Comment: Of course it would be helpful to post the code that crashes, rather than the code that works.  It would also be helpful to post information about the crash, like the backtrace.  However, taking a stab in the dark, I'm going to guess that you don't retain the font object, and so by the time you end up using it the pointer is no longer valid.

Comment: @bhaller I have updated my post to show the broken code (honestly, I don't know why I didn't just include it in the first place…).

Comment: You still didn't post the information about the crash. Are you compiling with Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)?

Comment: @KenThomases No ARC, I'm on Xcode 3.2.6 in Mountain Lion. Screen savers can't be debugged per se, so I'm not sure how to obtain relevant crash information. When System Preferences crashes, under 'Application Specific Signatures' it gives me `0   com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff91dc36db -[NSFont _isDefaultFace] + 22`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that you are not compiling with ARC, so my guess above is likely correct: you need to retain the font object.  Your line:

```
font = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:18];
```

should be:

```
font = [[NSFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:18] retain];
```

Without that retain, the font object goes away when the autorelease pool gets popped, since `fontWithName:size:` returns an autoreleased object.  You should `release` the retained font object in the `dealloc` method for your screensaver class, probably.  Apple has lots of good docs about memory management, `retain`/`release`/`autorelease`, etc.; if you are not using ARC (and even if you are, really), you need to read and understand this stuff or you will be plagued by bugs like this.  Here's a place to start: [About Memory Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).

Comment: Thank you very kindly, I knew it had to be something like this!